# PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[08004] [1040] Too many connections

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've got an error in my php file. The error says 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[08004] [1040] Too many connections'. I have looked around and people says that i should change the max_connections on the mysql server. I did that, but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you closing the connection in your script after you are done with it, or do you keep spawning new PDO objects and new connections willy nilly?

Comment: I'm closing it (i think) with: $pdo = null;

Answer (score 0):

You should use non-persistent connections. Details [in PHP Manual](http://am.php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php)

Comment: Persistent connections are not closed at the end of the script, but are cached and re-used when another script requests a connection using the same credentials. The persistent connection cache allows you to avoid the overhead of establishing a new connection every time a script needs to talk to a database, resulting in a faster web application. BUT this also results on too many connections being opened and not closed for a while so you might get that error. [see example #4](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.connections.php)

Comment: So i should change PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true to PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false?

Comment: i think it defaults to false, so you can omit that attribute at all

Comment: Then that's not the problem. Everytime i nead a connection to the server i use a class called Server::connect(). can i close the connection like this:

$pdo = Server::conect();
$pdo = null;

Comment: PDO documentation says that PDO connections are closed the way you do, but to be sure you should provide the code inside Server::conect() method.